# Paginate timeline groupBy date with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent, laravel-collection

I'm building a timeline for patients exams, they look like this:

[timeline patients exams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MqCT.png)

When I click in a patients will be showed all exams which he has done, the method used is:

```
return view('papeis.paciente.historico', [
        'vinculos' => Vinculo::where('paciente_id',$id)->get()->sortByDesc('admissao')
            ->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
                return $item->admissao->format('d/m/Y');
            }),
        'paciente' => Paciente::findOrFail($id),
    ]);
```

The patients exams ("Vinculo") are groupBy the date "admissao", to show the date and the exams who he did at that day. I can't use paginate a collection, so I don't have idea how to paginate a groupBy collection.

Comment: How would you like to paginate the exams?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/3ce756322702331fdf2bf414fea27bcb

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I would like to paginate by date, which page will have 5 dates, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Laravel natively supports that, but you can build it yourself:

```
$admissaoes = Vinculo::where('paciente_id', $id)->distinct()
    ->select('admissao')->orderByDesc('admissao')->get();
$page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1;
$perPage = 5;
$pageAdmissaoes = $admissaoes->forPage($page, $perPage);
$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($pageAdmissaoes, $admissaoes->count(), $perPage, $page);
$vinculos = Vinculo::where('paciente_id', $id)
    ->whereIn('admissao', $pageAdmissaoes->pluck('admissao'))
    ->orderByDesc('admissao')->get();
```